# How to pass on changements on server without to be forced to build manually all sub-modules changed?

Tags: maven, netbeans, jboss, module, hotdeploy

**Hello all !**

In my team we currently use Eclipse but I am not satisfied and I wanted to discover **netbeans** (8 version). It seems very nice. There is a good management of webprojects( angularJS, requirejs). There is a full integration of maven project and Java EE project, it's free ( not like intelliJ) and it seems more intuitive than eclipse et less strange/magic , more compréhensible (because full integration of maven)

There is a lot of points who could push my team to adopt this IDE but there is a problem,**a need that I can not satisfy**.

I have maven **modules projects with dependency mangement**. A parent project (called 'webParent' that contains a reference of a big parent project of the team.  'webParent' also contains a sub project 'WebProject' that is a java Webproject that contains web resources( html, js, css) and a java rest webservice management.

'WebProject' use service by injection dependency of an other project called 'business'.  'business' is a part of an other parent project called 'core'.  'core' contains modules that are 'business' (business services of application), 'dataAccess' (gather all DAO), 'External'  (gather all external webservice) and 'Authent' (authentication ..).

All these core modules are linked.

'business' need => 'dataAccess' , 'External', 'Authent'

'External' need => 'dataAccess'

'Authent' need => 'dataAccess'

Netbeans has perfectly integrated my project, no problem with that.

I could perfectly use my previous jboss install. Netbeans and jboss work perfectly together. but **my problem is that my modifications are not take in account by jboss on redeploy**.

I have installed this plugin in my webproject https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/

Indeed it work fine. When I need to redeploy my project I launch `jboss-as:redeploy` and a war is regenerated and sent to jboss. Jboss restart speedly and it's cool. But if I modify the java code
in my sub-modules (ex: business) I am forced to click on build button (the hammer) on each sub project I modified. Wait that build say  "nothing to compile (indeed the **compile on save is checked for all project**), regeneration of the jar module"

And I stop on this detail. The "jar". Indeed when I verify my local repository my module **jar is not changed with compile on save**, it's just the target folder of the project that is modified.

So when I launch the redeploy, the plugin launch the build of my webproject who search my modules jars on my local repository. And take a version not modified ..

This problem slowed a lot the developpement and because of it my team will never use netbeans in the future..

The other problem is that I am forced to lauch `jboss-as:redeploy` to redeploy web ressource (html, css, js) . For me its should be automatically repercuted on my server. But the problem is that jboss use a war that is generated on install.. What's the solution ? With eclipse it's not based entirely on maven (not cool) but the repercution of modification is very speed ( cool)

Help me to stay on netbeans ! ;)

Comment: And the winner is...[Eclipse](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=eclipse&word2=netbeans). ;-)

Comment: Re _"because full integration of maven"_ - What are you missing in Eclipse regarding Maven integration? With [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), for instance? You can even define your local Maven installation as external to be used in favour of the embedded in Eclipse.

Comment: Re _"It seems very nice."_ - If I had installed every piece of software that seemed nice to me I wouldn't have managed to get my job done. Even more if this had meant _replacing_ an existing, working, well-known, proven, supported by a strong and broad community piece.

Comment: Even if you think that eclipse is better, the question concerns netbeans ^^